# Where is ConfigDSN defined?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, odbc

I was trying to use [ConfigDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but received a linker error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ConfigDSNW@16 referenced in function ....
```

I checked exported symbols of the following odbc libraries under system32 but none of them have the definition of `ConfigDSN`

```
 odbc32.dll
 odbc32gt.dll
 odbcbcp.dll
 odbcconf.dll
 odbccp32.dll
 odbccr32.dll
 odbccu32.dll
 odbcint.dll
 odbctrac.dll
```

Comment: Is this a x64 application? I am not sure if these function is provided for both architectures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfigDSN is not defined by the driver manager which is made up of the ODBC DLLs you are looking at in the System32 folder. It is defined by each individual driver (or their setup DLLs) and is loaded and called by the driver manager when you call [SQLConfigDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The DLL which defines SQLConfigDataSource is odbccp32.dll.